# Error in SAP BI when trying to send report to destination

Tags: business-objects

When I select a report and try to send it to a destination I get this HTTPS error but cant find more info as to why I am getting that.

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error 
> Type Status Report
>
> Message javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.faces.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Error getting property 'dsGridContainer' from bean of type com.businessobjects.clientaction.shared.sendto.SendToDestinationBean
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Apache Tomcat/8.5.13

Anyone had such or can point me in the right direction ?

Comment: If it's a bug from SAP software and not your own program, this question is not relevant for stack overflow. Prefer searching and asking in SAP forum or SAP support. Or in [super user](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying that a setter(void) or getter(return type of its global variable of the same name and the variable it "returns") method with the name "dsGridContainer" in a bean class that is in a shared library application .jar file that has been loaded has an error when called.
*note a setter and getter (and also an "is" boolean method) have an associate global variable of the same name as the methods.
You may be able to get a better comprehensive error output in the server error.log file.